# Android - ImageView does not display image. Nor does setImageResource()

Tags: android, imageview

I use an ImageView control as shown:

```
<LinearLayout 
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >

     <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/imgHangMan"
        android:src="@drawable/hang0"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   />
</LinearLayout>
```

The above code displays the image in the Graphical Layout preview of the xml file. But on launching the app, I see no image. Also, changing the image using

```
imgHangMan = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imgHangMan);
imgHangMan.setImageResource(R.drawable.hang1);
```

This piece of code also does not work either. The image files are in .gif format and are in the drawable folder.

Any pointers ?

Comment: How are you creating or inflating the `View`? Are you sure your layout is even being shown? Try, for example, adding `android:background="#ff00"` to your `LinearLayout` and setting its width and height to `match_parent` to see if the layout is actually visible.

Comment: How do you know it's here, Dhaval? If it is, please direct him to the correct thread so this one can be closed.

Comment: The layout is being shown with the background as red. If I set the width and height to wrap_content, it displays the layout according to the orientation of the image.

Answer (score 5):

Natively ImageView doesnot support animated image. You have two options to show animated gif file

1) Use VideoView 2) Use ImageView. But Split the gif file into several parts and then apply animation to it.

Try this link-[playing-gif-animation](http://www.blindndumb.com/2012/02/android-tutorial-playing-gif-animation.html) you will get the desired result.

Comment: It will appear static in any sort of photo viewer,view the downloaded gif image in any browser.

Comment: Hi,I converted the gifs to PNG format and now it works. Thanks all for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
image.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.hang1));
```

Answer (score 0):

User this :
[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/AnimationDrawable.html](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/88b6e5/frame-by-frame-animation/)

[Go by this.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/AnimationDrawable.html)